Open and close a popup window in javascript
I tried to open and close a popup in a simple HTML page with javascript, but maybe im missing basic knowledge of JS. First I tried to declare global variable myPopupHandle.
But hat is'nt populated in myOpenWnd. Here is the code maybe somebody can help.


<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>WndCloseTest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button type="button" onclick="myOpenWnd()">Open Popup Window</button>
  <button type="button" onclick="myCloseWnd()">Close Popup Window</button>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
    let myPopUpHandle = null; // Always null
    window.addEventListener("onunload", function(e) {
      myCloseWnd();
    });

    function myCloseWnd() {
      if (windowObjectReference != null)
        windowObjectReference.close();
    }

    function myOpenWnd() {
      const windowFeatures = "left=100,top=100,width=320,height=320";
      /*
      myPopUpHandle = window.open(
          "https://www.mozilla.org/",
          "mozillaWindow",
          windowFeatures,
      );
      Don't work popUpHandle is null after this
       */


      const handle = window.open(
        "https://www.mozilla.org/",
        "mozillaWindow",
        windowFeatures,
      );
      if (!handle) {
        console.log("his is likely caused by built-in popup blockers"); // logs the className of my_element
        // The window wasn't allowed to open
        // This is likely caused by built-in popup blockers.
        // …
      } else
        window['windowObjectReference'] = handle;
    }
  </script>
</body>




It is hard to post HTML Code here in my real HTML code there are the closing script and body tags on the end of the code present.

Your code works as it is ..?

Not if I put the code in an HTML File and open it. Not from a apache server and not if I open in as local file in a browser.  In your test you put it to a external JS file ?! I have the JS script between the script tags.

http://213.220.158.209/jstest/index.html

The source of JS code doesn't matter at all. In jsFIddle the script in the separate window is placed just before the closing body tag on the display page.

As the popup window and the parent window are from different origin, you can't directly close the popup window programmatically due to the same-origin policy, which restricts interactions between scripts from different origins for security reasons.
Read the docs at MDN
If the website from a different domain allows being embedded within an iframe and doesn't have any security restrictions preventing it, you can indeed open it within an iframe in a popup window and close it programmatically from parent window.
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>WndCloseTest</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button type="button" onclick="myOpenWnd()">Open Popup Window</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="myCloseWnd()">Close Popup Window</button>
    <script>
        var popup;
        function myOpenWnd() {
            var popup = window.open("", "", "popup");
            popup.document.write('<iframe style="width:100%; height:100%; display:block;" id="popupFrame" src="' + 'https://www.wikipedia.org/' + '" frameborder="0"></iframe>');
            if (!popup || popup.closed || typeof popup.closed == 'undefined') {
                alert("Popup window was blocked by the browser. Please allow popups for this site.");
            }
            window['popupWin'] = popup;
        }
        
        function myCloseWnd() {
            popupWin.close();
            console.log("closed");
        }
    </script>
</body>

https://jsfiddle.net/shardulvikrm/Lhq59ov4/

Why is that? The created pop-up object is still on caller's domain, same-origin-policy prevents only accessing the cross-domain content.

I also did'nt understand that , and also there is no COORS warning, but I will try with a URL that is on the same server.

The popup window URL is https://www.mozilla.org/ which is different from the parent window domain

@ShardulVikramSingh Please run the fiddle I've linked in a comment above, you can open and close a pop-up window with that code perfectly fine (the content of the external window is not loaded due to the security settings of mozilla.org).

OK, you are right, if I open a popup from my own site I can close it via button , but it did'nt close onunload which I was finally wan't to. Check again http://213.220.158.209/jstest/index.html

Damn , the event is called unload NOT onunload. Now it works. Thanks to all, all informations were helpfull.

Check that your browser does not block popup as your comment says.

The popup appears and ist not blocked, but I can't close it:

check that link http://213.220.158.209/jstest/index.html
